# convert text date string to valid date value in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a flat text file that stores a date as YYMMDD that could also be 000000.  When attempting to use a derrived column to extract this information, I am running into the issue that 00-00-00 is not a valid DT_DATE.

I worked around this as such to check each part to ensure it was a valid date component:

`(DT_DATE)("20"+SubString( [CardData], 1451, 2 )+"-"+(SubString( [CardData], 1453, 2 )=="00" ? "01":SubString( [CardData], 1453, 2 ))+"-"+ (SubString( [CardData], 1455, 2 )=="00"?"01":SubString( [CardData], 1455, 2 )))`

But that leaves me with  bunch of 01-01-2000 dates that aren't legitimate dates.  I the run a post processing command to clean that up with REPLACENULL to Nullify the values meeting that criteria.  I don't like this as it's terribly inefficient.

I tried the following:

`("00"+(SubString( [CardData], 1451, 2 ))+"-"+(SubString( [CardData], 1453, 2 ))+"-"+(SubString( [CardData], 1455, 2 )))== "0000-00-00" ? Null(DT_DATE):(DT_DATE)("20"+(SubString( [CardData], 1451, 2 ))+"-"+(SubString( [CardData], 1453, 2 ))+"-"+(SubString( [CardData], 1455, 2 )))`

This is also not working.  I suspect that it's ALWAYS evaluating the second expression and therefore is failing because 0000-00-00 isn't a valid DT_DATE. What am I missing?

Comment: Use try_convert()    For example:  Select try_convert(date,'230529'),try_convert(date,'000000')